# what is the degree of field extension over base field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

What is the degree of field extension ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt[8]{2},\sqrt[16]{2})$ over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: What did you try? Show us your work so far.

Comment: Is that $\sqrt{2^{1/8}}$, or $\root8\of2$?

Comment: 2^1/16 = √2^1/8

Comment: Degrees of splitting field of polynomials satisfied by 2^1/2,2^1/16^2^1/8 are 2,32 and 16 respectively. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Can you write that field extension as a simple extension? In fact, can you see that one particular element that you are adjoining that you have written can generate the entire extension? That element has an obvious polynomial that it satisfies, and you can show it to be irreducible using Eisenstein.

Comment: I don't get what you mean : $X^3-2$ is irreducible but $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ is not of degree $3$

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, it's the splitting field that isn't. It's a fact that adjoining a root of an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ yields a degree $n$ extension...

Comment: yes it is of degree $3$, I confound splitting field of $P$ and  $\simeq \mathbb{Q}[X]/(P(X))$. how do you see the degree of a splitting field ?

Comment: and here the splitting field would be $L = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/16},\zeta_{16})$ of degree $[L:\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/16})] \, [\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/16}):\mathbb{Q}] = 8 . 16$ ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, because it isn't clear to me that the degree of $\zeta_{16}$ is 8 over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/16})$, though it is over $\mathbb{Q}$. For instance, $\zeta_8$ has degree 2, not 4, over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/8})$, even though it has degree 4 over the rationals.

Comment: yes $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2^k},\zeta_{2^k})/\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2^k})$ is at most $2^{k-2}$ because when we add $i$ to $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2^k})$ we get $\zeta_8 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)$ for the same price, and then it depends if  $X^2-\zeta_8$ is irreducible in it, and if $X^2-\zeta_{2^m}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2^k},\zeta_{2^m})$